# Collapse forwarding in Apache Disptacher

Tags: apache, dispatcher, aem

I'm wondering if it's possible to enable collapsed forwarding for Apache dispatcher in the same way that Varnish or Squid collapse multiple requests.

We are using CQ5, which does some pretty heavy duty transformation in the background, and I don't want multiple requests hitting through to the origin.

Any help on whether you can and how you can enable this feature would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should look at why you have so many requests. Images etc should only be required from your publish once and then cached on the dispatcher, so no more requests would be going to the publish.

for javascript/css you can combine the clientlibs in a single file by using embed. check out this source to see how you should configure your clientlibs to combine all your js and css files into 1

http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2012/12/clientlibs-explained-by-example.html

Comment: To give you a bit of an idea, we have one page with roughly 1 million hits per day. The site contains several more like that. We have Akamai sitting in front of that, but we would still have problem when cache is invalidated where a flood of requests can come back. We do aggregate files together and limit requests as much as possible.